# ValidationContext is declared but its value is never read?

Tags: typescript

I have the following:

```
    const validators:Array<ValidationContext> = 
    ValidationContainer.getValidationContexts(key);

    const value:any = o[propertyName];
```

So far so good.  No errors.  Now I want to iterate over the `validators` array like this:

```
    validators.forEach(vc:ValidationContext => {
        vc.validate(value);
    });
```

VSCode provides the following error:

```
[ts] 'ValidationContext' is declared but its value is never read.
[ts] Parameter 'ValidationContext' implicitly has an 'any' type.
(parameter) ValidationContext: any
```

Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must surround your typed parameters of an arrow function with parenthesis

```
validators.forEach((vc:ValidationContext) => {
    vc.validate(value);
});
```